# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info. Syntax error with pip install. How to solve it?

Tags: pip, syntax-error

I'm encountering a problem while installing FoBiS with pip.

**Input:** pip install FoBiS.py

**Returns:**

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/femke/Programs/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rumwdmo2/multiprocessing/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-rumwdmo2/multiprocessing/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-s25t8ebi
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-rumwdmo2/multiprocessing/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-rumwdmo2/multiprocessing/setup.py", line 94
        print 'Macros:'
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('Macros:')?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**System:** Linux Ubuntu 20.4 LTS, Python 3.8.3

I tried to update the setuptools. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the package. The package [requires dependencies](https://github.com/szaghi/FoBiS/blob/7d7153c392b03c5c3d83b2ab044ead10635c7a6c/src/main/scripts/setup.py#L34) that are actually Python standard modules. With the bug `pip` is trying to install [very old Python2-only version of `multiprocessing`](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing/).

The bug was [introduced recently](https://github.com/szaghi/FoBiS/issues/117) and presents in version 3.0.3. Try to install older version like 3.0.2:

```
pip install FoBiS.py==3.0.2
```

I reported the bug: https://github.com/szaghi/FoBiS/issues/117#issuecomment-684895781